# Can I Get User's Location Without Using MapKit? Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am getting the user's location using the MapKit.

When I get the user's location I want to delete (get rid of) the map but still display the address of the user.

Is there any way to make this?

When I delete the map I get many errors because I get the location from the map only.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the map? Do you want to hide the app or delete it? You can just get the user's location and then display the location in a label.

Comment: I said delete the Map, not the App :) . Anyway, how do I still get the location and display it on a label without using any map?

Comment: Yes sorry! Meant to say Map. Why do you want to delete the map?

Comment: Because I don't want to display its street/city address on a map, only on a label

Comment: In that case you don't need to "delete" the map. You just don't need to display the address.

Comment: But I get the location by the map .. and when I delete the map I get errors as I said in the subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100417/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-eliko).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100419/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-eliko).

Answer (score 3):

Use `CLLocationManager` from `CoreLocation` instead https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/

Comment: How do I convert it into code?